# How to insert into two tables from the same two joined tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am updating a database table with company names hard coded into column names to a more flexible design. The table currently looks like this:

```
table: transactions (current)
| id | contract_id | company_a_tot | company_b_tot | company_c_tot |
| -- | ----------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- |
| 1  |       10    |    200        |    300        |    400        |
```

I would like to achieve this design:

```
table: transactions (new)
| id | contract_id | company | total |
| -- | ----------- | ------- | ----- |
| 1  |    10       |    a    |   200 |
| 2  |    101      |    b    |   300 |
| 3  |    102      |    c    |   400 |
```

There is a second table named contracts related to transactions. 
For each new row I create on the transactions table I need to create a corresponding row on the contracts table.

```
table: contracts
| id  | data |
| --- | ---- |
| 10  |   x  |
| 101 |   x  |
| 102 |   x  |
```

On the transactions table I will need to insert a new row for all but one company column. 
In the example above, the transaction row with an id of 1 expands to three transaction rows.
I can successfully expand transactions from the old table to the new, but for each new row I create on the transactions table I need to create a corresponding row on the contracts table.
I have tried using data-modifying statements with no luck.

```
WITH ins AS (
    INSERT INTO contracts(data)
    SELECT contracts.data
    FROM contracts
    RIGHT JOIN transactions
    ON contracts.id=transactions.contract_id
    RETURNING contracts.id as c_id, transactions.id as t_id, transactions.data AS t_data
)
UPDATE transactions
    SET contract_id=ins.c_id, data=ins.t_data
    FROM ins
    WHERE id=ins.t_id;
```

I get the following error:

```
'missing FROM-clause entry for table "transactions"' 
on line 'returning contracts.id as c_id, transactions.id as t_id, transactions.data as t_data'
```

I am new to queries of this type and complexity. Can I not include a join inside a data-modifying with statement? How can I access both tables outside the statement? Is there a different better approach?